# UIWebview video playing crash - Limited to jw player in HTML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I noticed a weird behavior of `UIWebview` today.

When you open a `Uiwebview` in a modal view & play a video. Once the complete video is played, we `dismiss` the `uiwebview` and on calling it again, we get a crash.

Interesting point to note here is that this behavior is only present in `iPad` & works fine in `iPhone`.

On debugging & enabling zombies it pointed to

`[MPTransportButton _isChargeEnabled]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7530930`.

**The caller:**

```
#import "POCViewController.h"
#import "POCWebViewController.h"

@interface POCViewController ()

@end

@implementation POCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)displayWebview:(id)sender {
    POCWebViewController *objPOCWebViewController = [[POCWebViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:objPOCWebViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [objPOCWebViewController release];
}
@end
```

**The `UIWebview` containing viewcontroller**

```
#import "POCWebViewController.h"

@interface POCWebViewController ()

@end

@implementation POCWebViewController
@synthesize webview;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSURL *usl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Any Youtube url"];
    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:usl];
    [webview loadRequest:urlReq];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    if(webview != nil)
    [webview release], webview = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)dismissTapped:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Any idea as to where I am going wrong?

**EDIT 1:  After playing with the code I observed that the defect was limited to 'jw-player' being used in HTML, i.e flash & other players were fine.**

**You can try to open the same POC with this link `http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/`. This uses a jw-player.**

**When the complete video is played, if you dismiss the `view controller` containing the `uiwebview` & present it again, it will lead to a crash.**

Comment: I'd like to recommend to you to use YouTubeVideoPlayer https://github.com/surajwebo/YouTubeVideoPlayer . I use it. It works fine.

Comment: Its not just about playing youtube videos, but any HTML with an embedded video is behaving the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to play video in web view its working for me both youtube and vimeo video,if do you have any query let me know.

```
NSString *youTubeID = @"YOUR YOUTUBE ID";
 NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                          <html><head>\
                          <style type=\"text/css\">\
                          body {\
                          background-color: #666666;\
                          padding:%f %f %f %f;\
                          color: blue;\
                          }\
                          </style>\
                          </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                          <iframe height=\"%f\" width=\"%f\" title=\"YouTube Video\" class=\"youtube-player\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" ></iframe>\
                          </body></html>",paddingTop,paddingRight,paddingBottom,paddingLeft,videoHeight,videoWidth,youTubeID];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```